# AuthenticationFailureException: The oauth state was missing or invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth, razor-pages

i'm a newbie and now i want use google oauth to login my application but i get error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This is my program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Project.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

// Oauth with google
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("GoogleKeys:ClientId").Value;
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("GoogleKeys:ClientSecret").Value;
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
app.UseSession();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
//app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
app.MapHub<ChatWithSpecifyUser>("/chatWithUser");

app.Run();
```

This is my LoginWithGoogle a model of razor page:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Project.Pages.Auth
{
    public class LoginWithGoogleModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Page("./GoogleResponse")
                });
        }
    }
}
```

And i have another razor page to get redirecUri:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Project.Services;
using Project.ViewModels.Auth;
using NuGet.Protocol;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Project.Pages.Auth
{
    public class GoogleResponseModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AuthService authService = new AuthService();
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var Claims = result.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims
                .Select(claim => new
                {
                    claim.Value,
                    claim.Issuer,
                    claim.OriginalIssuer,
                    claim.Type,
                });
            string email = Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
            string name = Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            LoginResponse response = authService.GetLoginResponseFromEmail(email, name);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("user", response.ToJson());

            return Redirect("chat");
        }
    }
}
```

I find error on google, after some hours I still cannot fix this error, help me

Comment: Hi Nghĩa Đỗ Minh, please uncomment this line `//app.UseAuthentication();`. If you are using authentication, this line is needed.